# Live agent with my own web site

Tags: liveagent

I think I know the answer but I would like to make sure, can I integrate SF Live Agent into my own web site or only into pages built on SF Site/Portal?

Comment: Yes you can use custom prechat and post chat forms and also customise the chat window itself. You simply need to plugin the urls into the Live Agent config on Salesforce. And embed the markup Salesforce gives you for the Chat Button into your website. http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/live_agent_dev/live_agent_dev_guide.pdf

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can use custom prechat and post chat forms and also customise the chat window itself, and host the pages on a Force.com Site or your own website. You simply need to plugin the urls into the Live Agent config on Salesforce. 
To show the button on your website, embed the markup Salesforce gives you for the Chat Button into your webpage.

http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/live_agent_dev/live_agent_dev_guide.pdf

Answer (score 1):

You can absolutely integrate it into your own site. If you have a pre-chat questionnaire etc, you can expose that on your own site in a popup / iframe...